# Fragment Lifecycle, i want refresh using only for button click

Tags: android, android-fragments

**CODE:**

```
public class YellowFragment extends Fragment implements FlowerAdapter.FlowerClickListener{

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private FlowerAdapter mFlowerAdapter;

    private Button mRefreshButton;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_yellow, container, false);

        mRefreshButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.refreshbutton);
        mRefreshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //I want this button for refresh, i want my fragment be refreshed when just through click this button.
            }
        });

        if (mFlowerApiService==null) {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.HTTP.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            mFlowerApiService = retrofit.create(FlowerApiService.class);
        }

        Call<List<Flower>> listCall = mRestManager.getmFlowerApiService(getActivity()).getAllFlowers();
        listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Flower>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Flower>> call, Response<List<Flower>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    List<Flower> flowerList = response.body();
                    for(int i =0; i<flowerList.size(); i++) {
                        Flower flower = flowerList.get(i);
                        mFlowerAdapter.addFlower(flower);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Flower>> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

**fragment_yellow.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ddff00">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/refreshbutton" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_flower"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm making application that shows `RecyclerView` using `retrofit2`.

That `RecyclerView` is on `YellowFragment`, but when I open or click that `YellowFragment`, the `RecyclerView` is refreshed automatically.

I don't want this refreshing this way.

I want to refresh only through a button click (`mRefreshButton`).

I had another fragment(`BlueFragment`), and that `BlueFragment` showing data (which is from my RESTapi and same for `YellowFragment`'s data) in `GridLayout`.

As you can see above code, `YellowFragment` shows data in `LinearLayout`.

I want these `BlueFragment` and `YellowFragment` to share the same data.

Therefore I want button to unite refershing.

Maybe i think answer is on `FragmentLifecycle`, I don't know the way to solve it. It's too hard.

**Question**

How to use `mRefreshButton` to refresh?

How to make `BlueFragment` and `YellowFragment` to share data and to refresh at the same time?

Please, I'm waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How to use mRefreshButton to refresh?"

you can have a main method , for example loadMyData() for connecting to your web service and refresh your adapter by notifyDatasetChanged method.and you can call this method on your onCreateView and mRefreshButton click listener.

"How to make BlueFragment and YellowFragment to share data and to refresh at the same time?"
put a public field in your activity, for example :

```
public String mySharedString;
```

you can read and change this data from your fragments this way :

```
((yourActivityName) getActivity()).mySharedString //do whatever you want
```